# Is there any API in EOS Smart Contract to decrypt message?

Tags: smart-contract, cryptography

I would like to create a smart contract that would be able to decrypt some symmetrically encrypted message.

Here is the scenario:

- Party "A" sends a message encrypted with key "123456" to VerifierContract
- Party "B" sends a plain message with key "123456" to VerifierContract
- VerifierContract decrypts "A" message using the key from "B".
- if decrypted message is equal to "B" plain message, then VerifierContract takes action.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't really get what you're trying to build but here's the [cryptoapi](https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.4.0/group__cryptoapi.html).